# right-to-left text (like Hebrew)

Tags: c#, localization, right-to-left, globalization, hebrew

On c#. Winforms. whenever I try to write Parenthesis in text-box in Hebrew\Arabic, they get inverted
and are on the other side of the text ( right when they should be on the left).

I tried these things and none of them seemed to work for me:

- Setting the RightToLeft property for the textbox
- Choosing a font that supports Hebrew characters.
- Changing the form Language property in the design view to Hebrew.

Comment: Show the code as a [mre]. That's what you need to do for most Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: You probably also want to show us what you mean by _"they get inverted and are on the other side of the text ( right when they should be on the left)."_. Show your code as text formatted as `code`, but it's OK to show the output as an image.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is due to the fact that Arabic is written and read from right to left. I don’t know about Hebrew, but I think it’s the same.

If you want this to not happen, then try processing your text first. For example, you can try to do something like:

```
string myString = "Some Arabiс text here".ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```